# Passing a path parameter to Google's Endpoint for Cloud Function

Tags: aws-lambda, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-endpoints, openapi

I am following Google's [tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/get-started-cloud-functions) on setting up **Google Cloud endpoint** (not AWS API Gateway) in front of my Cloud Function. I am triggering my Cloud Function to trigger an AWS lambda function, AND I am trying to pass a `path parameter` from my Endpoint as defined by OpenAPI [spec](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/describing-parameters/).

> Path parameters are variable parts of a URL path. They are typically used to point to a specific resource within a collection, such as a user identified by ID. A URL can have several path parameters, each denoted with curly braces { }.
>
> ```
> paths:   /users/{id}:
>     get:
>       parameters:
>         - in: path
>           name: id   # Note the name is the same as in the path
>           required: true
>           schema: 
>             type: integer
> ```
>
> `GET /users/{id}`

My `openapi.yaml`

```
swagger: '2.0'
info:
  title: Cloud Endpoints + GCF
  description: Sample API on Cloud Endpoints with a Google Cloud Functions backend
  version: 1.0.0
host: HOST
x-google-endpoints:
- name: "HOST"
  allowCors: "true
schemes:
  - https
produces:
  - application/json
paths:
  /function1/{pathParameters}:
    get:
      operationId: function1
      parameters:
      - in: path
        name: pathParameters
        required: true
        type: string
      x-google-backend:
        address: https://REGION-FUNCTIONS_PROJECT_ID.cloudfunctions.net/function1
      responses:
        '200':
          description: A successful response
          schema:
            type: string
```

The error I get when I use Endpoint URL `https://REGION-FUNCTIONS_PROJECT_ID.cloudfunctions.net/function1/conversations` is a TypeError from my AWS lambda function

```
StatusCode:200, FunctionError: "Unhandled", ExecutedVersion: "$LATEST". Payload: "errorType":"TypeError", errorMessage:"Cannot read property 'startsWith' of undefined..."
```

It is saying that on line

```
var path = event.pathParameters;
...
...
if (path.startsWith('conversations/'){...};
```

my `path` var is undefined.

I initially thought my Google Function was not correctly passing `pathParameters` but when I tested my Google function using triggering event `{"pathParameters":"conversations"}`, my Lambda returns the payload successfully.

My Google Cloud Function:

```
let AWS = require('aws-sdk');

AWS.config.update({
  accessKeyId: 'key',
  secretAccessKey: 'secret',
  region: 'region'
})

let lambda = new AWS.Lambda();

exports.helloWorld = async(req,res) => {
  let params = {
     FunctionName:'lambdafunction',
     InvocationType: "RequestRespone",
     Payload: JSON.stringify(req.body)
  };

  res.status(200).send(await lambda.invoke(params, function(err,data){
      if(err){throw err}
      else{
         return data.Payload
      }
   }).promise());
}
```

**EDIT 1:**

Seeing this Google Group [post](https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en-GB#!topic/google-cloud-endpoints/7USlE86FFsg), I tried adding to my `openapi.yaml` file `path_translation: APPEND_PATH_TO_ADDRESS`, yet still I'm having no luck.

```
...
paths:
  /{pathParameters}:
    get:
     ...
     x-google-backend:
       address: https://tomy.cloudfunctions.net/function-Name
       path_translation: APPEND_PATH_TO_ADDRESS
```

@Arunmainthan Kamalanathan mentioned in the comments that testing in AWS and Google Cloud directly with trigger event `{"pathParameters":"conversations"}` is not equivalent to passing `req.body` from my Google function to AWS lambda. I think this is where my error is occurring -- I'm not correctly passing my path parameter in the payload.

**EDIT 2:**

There is this Stackoverflow [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42145759/do-google-cloud-platform-http-functions-support-route-parameters) concerning passing route parameters to Cloud Functions using `req.path`. When I `console.log(req.path)` I get `/` and `console.log(req.params)` I get `{'0': '' }`, so for some reason my path parameter is not getting passed correctly from Cloud Endpoint URL to my Google function.

Comment: I think `event.pathParameters` is the way of identifying the parameters in the path. can you try using another parameter name in your openapi specification.

Comment: The reason why your lambda work when you trigger it directly is , you are passing the values directly to the lambda's event. when you have a parameter defined in the path, it can be accessible from the lambda as `event.pathParameters`. But in your case `pathParameters` is the parameter name. try changing the parameter name and see if it's working.

Comment: For lambda, its not either of those. you can pass a json body , query string or headers and test the lambda. I haven't use google functions.

Answer (score 5):

I was running into the same issue when specifying multiple paths/routes within my openapi.yaml. It all depends on where you place the x-google-backend (top-level versus operation-level). This has implications on the behaviour of the path_translation. You could also overwrite path_translation yourself, as the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/openapi-extensions) clearly describes:

> path_translation: [ APPEND_PATH_TO_ADDRESS | CONSTANT_ADDRESS ]
>
> Optional. Sets the path translation strategy used by ESP when making
> target backend requests.
>
> Note: When x-google-backend is used at the top level of the OpenAPI
> specification, path_translation defaults to APPEND_PATH_TO_ADDRESS,
> and when x-google-backend is used at the operation level of the
> OpenAPI specification, path_translation defaults to CONSTANT_ADDRESS.
> For more details on path translation, please see the Understanding
> path translation section.

This means that if you want the path to be appended as a path parameter instead of a query parameter in your backend, you should adhere to the following scenario's:

**Scenario 1**: Do you have one cloud function in the `x-google-backend.address` that handles all of your paths in the openapi specification? Put `x-google-backend` at the top-level.

**Scenario 2**: Do you have multiple cloud functions corresponding to different paths? Put `x-google-backend` at the operation-level and set `x-google-backend.path_translation` to `APPEND_PATH_TO_ADDRESS`.

Answer (score 0):

When your invocation type is `RequestRespone`, you can access the payload directly from the `event` parameter of lambda.

Look at the `Payload' parameter of the Google function:

```
let params = {
   FunctionName:'lambdafunction',
   InvocationType: "RequestRespone",
   Payload: JSON.stringify({ name: 'Arun'})
};

res.status(200).send(await lambda.invoke(params)...)
```

Also the Lambda part:

```
exports.handler = function(event, context) {
  context.succeed('Hello ' + event.name);
};
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I changed my path parameter name as instructed and edited my `yaml` accordingly, but I'm still getting the same error. Please let me know if you need any further information to debug this issue.

Comment: My bad, i got it wrong.lets start over.  How are you calling your lambda, though api gateway or directly.

Comment: Directly by hardcoding my AWS `accessKeyId` and `secretAccessKey` within my Google function, which is secured with Google IAM.

Comment: are you executing like this `curl -X POST https://lambda.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/2015-03-31/functions/Function_NAME/invocations` without using an API gateway, correct?

Comment: Edit: That's incorrect. I'm going through Google cloud Endpoint's URL `curl -X GET https://service-name.a.run.app/function-name/myParameter`. This is triggering my Google function. I'll add the Google function to the original post

Comment: good. in that case, you can send the parameter as a query string `/2015-03-31/functions/FunctionName/invocations?param=conversation`. inside the lambda, you can access it as `event.queryParameters`

Comment: Inside your google cloudfunction, how do you call your aws lambda from your google function

Comment: Ok. edited my answer. you invoke the lambda as a `RequestResponse`, you can directly access it from the `event` parameter of lambda handler function

Comment: Great! Now if I need to pass the parameter value from Google endpoint, would I do `Payload: JSON.stringify({ pathParameters: req.body.myParameters})`?

Comment: I am not sure what you get in the `req.body` since i haven't used google cloud functions before, however if `req.body.myParameters` has the value `conversation` for e,g, then you are good to go.

Comment: I think `req.body` is only applicable if the google cloud function is called as a post request.

Comment: to get the arguments on the URL you can use  `req.url`